# LINQ Cache issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am pretty new to LINQ and having a issue with what seems to be irregular content caching. The website in question has 6 content areas of different subjects now on the odd occasion the content just blanks out to nothing or has the same content for all 6 areas. It will clear up this issue by itself over time or the only other way to fix it is to recycle the app pool :(

Have tried using

DBLocal.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, ret)

but this caused similar problems.

Has anyone else come across this problem as I cannot seem to find anything about it online

Thanks
Clinton

ADDED CODE:

```
Dim discussionDetails As Model.Discussion = Services.Discussion.getById(discussionId)


Public Function getById(ByVal discussionId As Integer) As Model.Discussion
Dim _discussion As Model.Discussion = DBLocal.Discussions.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.DiscussionId.Equals(discussionId))
Return _discussion
End Function
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "cannot" in the last sentence :-).

To answer this, we need a lot more information.

Comment: Could you please post your LINQ code as well as the code that assigns the results to the various content areas?

Comment: Add the code above for a page that pulls a discussion from the database by its ID.

Basically this function is returning nothing even though there is content :(

Comment: Do you mean LINQ, or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: LINQ to SQL

Sorry I didn't code this part of the system so its all new to me. Is there any chance this could be a config error with the app pool or a server issue? As the code works most of the time!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the lifecycle of the DBLocal instance.  It should be per-request at longest, and per-unitofwork ideally.

You haven't shown us the code that assigns the discussion to a content area, nor the code that calls this method (how frequently is it called and where does that code get Ids from?)

Consider these cases.

- SingleOrDefault returns null, if there is no matching instance.
- SingleOrDefault throws if there is more than one matching instance.

Comment: The Id is return from the URL using "Request.QueryString" which triggers a function called updatepage(id).
Then discussionDetails is defined as in the code above and then it replaces some HTML Keywords on the page like so :
 strHTML = strHTML.Replace("#NUMBER_OF_VIEWS", discussionDetails.NumberOfViews.ToString())